# Error archive on vmchecker

Tags: makefile

I made an archive in which there are the next files: tema1.c (code), Makefile, input.txt, output.txt, and when I upload it on vmchecker(it's a homework checker), after compiling, at EXECUTING TESTS, I receive this error: file 'tema1" is not in the same directory as this script. What does it mean?

Comment: Does your code compile succesfully? It's very hard to say without additional details on the setup. As a guess there might be a compilation error and the binary isn't being generated?

Comment: I found the error. It was a problem in makefile.